# How to run a .bat file as a Scheduled task from a php script

Tags: php, batch-file

I have searched a lot but I didn't find the correct way to proceed , Here is my php Code

```
$command  = "cmd /c start Schtasks.exe /create /SC WEEKLY /D MON /TN \"hamdi\" /TR \"C:/wamp64/www/stage/jobs/Nouveau.bat\" /ST 00:00"
exec($commande ,$array,  $return_val);
```

The same command works perfectly through prompt command line but it has no effect when i run it from a php file.

can any one help me please ?

Comment: You might have to use the absolute path to the `Schtasks.exe` executable, depending on the setup of your http server.

Comment: In the official documentation it says there is no need for the path of schtasks

Comment: What official documentation are you referring to? Certainly it might be that the process in the web environment that executes the script has another `$PATH` environment variable defined as your interactive shell.

Comment: I am refering to the Microsoft documentation 

[link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490996.aspx)

any way how shall I proceed ?

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with the details of a MS-Windows environment, as most programmers I work under a unixoid environment. But one question: do you need to `cmd` stuff at all? Why can't you directly execute the `Schtasks.exe` command?

Comment: I have tried both ways and I got nothing

Comment: The you will have to start debugging, right? First obvious point to start is: take a look into your http servers error log file. Any entries? Second, what does the `exec()` command return and what does `$return_val` contain after the call?

Comment: the $return_val is equal to 0 and the $array is empty

Answer (score 0):

```
$command  = "cmd /c start Schtasks.exe /create /SC WEEKLY /D MON /TN \"hamdi\" /TR \"C:/wamp64/www/stage/jobs/Nouveau.bat\" /ST 00:00"
exec($command);
```

Comment: @hamdi can you maybe also post the response you get?

Comment: The problem is that I get nothing, i have tried to print the $return_val and $array , and I get : 0 for $return_val and the $array is empty

Comment: by the way , i have used the folowing command to add permission to the user to run schtasks 

     Cacls "c:\windows\tasks" /e /t /g "Hamdi":F